# Cosmos re-indexing takes longer than expected

Tags: indexing, azure-cosmosdb, cosmos

Cosmos re-indexing takes longer than expected. 
Is there any way i can check if re-indexing is still happening for partitioned collection.
Even though I made the index policy to none and kept back consistent, the query is throwing an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can view the percentage progress by reading the `x-ms-documentdb-collection-index-transformation-progress` header in GET collection. For example in .NET, you can run the following snippet:

```
// retrieve the container's details
ContainerResponse containerResponse = await client.GetContainer("database", "container")
    .ReadContainerAsync(new ContainerRequestOptions { PopulateQuotaInfo = true });
// retrieve the index transformation progress from the result
long indexTransformationProgress = long.Parse(
    containerResponse.Headers["x-ms-documentdb-collection-index-transformation-progress"]);
```

More details here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/how-to-manage-indexing-policy#updating-indexing-policy

Comment: I need to check the status when updating the policies via portal